# Finding Forbidden Strings Program

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I recently came across this question stated below:

A string is said to be forbidden if there are three consecutive letters from which one is A, one is B,
and one is C. For example BAAAACABCC is forbidden but AAABBBCCC is not.
You are given an integer n. You have to find how many strings of length n are not forbidden. (n will be from 1 to 30)
Example: If n=2, then none of the string is forbidden. So output is 9.

I tried but couldn't find an efficient solution for this. I did write a bruteforce algo for this, wherein I check all possible such strings, but since it is an exponential algo, it is damn slow. You can find my code [here](http://pastebin.com/6hkffiEa)

Can someone guide me an efficient algo for this, maybe using dynamic programming or any other way.

Thank You

Comment: Not sure if this is cheating or not, but what'd I do is take the first few solutions from the brute force and put them through http://oeis.org/ and see if you get any hits.

Comment: As a general clue, when dealing with counting interview problems the answer is in general either a mathematical formula or some dynamic programming or a combination of both... and never is it a brute-force solution. To get started, using brute-force to generate the first terms of the serie may give a clue as to the mathematical formula, or doing the first steps by hand may give a clue as to a dynamic programming approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic programming can be applied here.

Say you know the number of non-forbidden sequences for n = k. Now if you add another letter, then the number of combinations become 3k. However you have to discard the new combinations that become forbidden.

The last two letters of any sequence can be:

```
ab
ac
bc
ba
ca
cb
bb
aa
cc
```

Form the series you provided, it seems
The number of combinations to discard for (k+1) = the number of new additions for (k)

EDIT:
Why is this so?
Say out of the 3k combinations, we first discard k combinations saying out of all the previous sequences we will discard 1/3rd.

Now out of these k combinations discarded, there are a few combinations that have a repeated letter at the end (aa, bb, or cc). We did not have to discard those sequences.

**The number of such sequences shall be equal to number of unforbidden sequences for (k-1) because for each new sequence that we make for n=k, we can have one and only one new sequence of a repeated letter.**

```
Hence if f(k) = number of unforbidden combinations for n = k, 
 then f(k + 1) = 3f(k) - [f(k)-f(k-1)]. 

For example for n=3 the number of sequences with repeated letter at the end shall be 9.  
For n=4 the number of sequences with repeated letter at the end shall be 21.  
... and so on.
```

Comment: hey nice approach, but am not getting hw the no of combinations to discard is f[k] - f[k-1]

Comment: Neither do I :) can't think, its 12:00am here!

Answer (score 2):

From the look of the series: 3,9,21,51,123 the next number is 123 * 2 + 51 = 297

Comment: hey, nice observation this seems to work, [edit] ok got it :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this dynamic programming approach, where `C[x,y]` means *the number of not forbidden strings of length `x`, which end with the two-char sequence `y`*:

```
C [n, 'AA'] = C[n-1, 'AA'] + C[n-1, 'AB'] + C[n-1, 'AC']
C [n, 'AB'] = C[n-1, 'BA'] + C[n-1, 'BB']
C [n, 'AC'] = C[n-1, 'CA'] + C[n-1, 'CB'] + C[n-1, 'CC']
C [n, 'BA'] = C[n-1, 'AA'] + C[n-1, 'AB'] + C[n-1, 'AC']
C [n, 'BB'] = C[n-1, 'BA'] + C[n-1, 'BB'] + C[n-1, 'BC']
C [n, 'BC'] = C[n-1, 'CA'] + C[n-1, 'CB'] + C[n-1, 'CC']
C [n, 'CA'] = C[n-1, 'AA'] + C[n-1, 'AB'] + C[n-1, 'AC']
C [n, 'CB'] = C[n-1, 'BA'] + C[n-1, 'BB'] + C[n-1, 'BC']
C [n, 'CC'] = C[n-1, 'CA'] + C[n-1, 'CB'] + C[n-1, 'CC']
```

with boundary conditions `n >= 3, C[3, x] = 3, C[3, 'AB'] = 2` ?

And a straightforward program, no sure if correct, but sure enough to risk some downvoting, if it's wrong, hehe :)

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int C[100][9];

// AA  0
// AB  1
// AC  2
// BA  3
// BB  4
// BC  5
// CA  6
// CB  7
// CC  8

void
calc (unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        C[3][i] = 3;
    C[3][1] = 2;

    for (i = 4; i <= n; ++i) {
        C[i][0] = C[i-1][0] + C[i-1][1] + C[i-1][2];
        C[i][1] = C[i-1][3] + C[i-1][4];
        C[i][2] = C[i-1][6] + C[i-1][7] + C[i-1][8];
        C[i][3] = C[i-1][0] + C[i-1][1] + C[i-1][2];
        C[i][4] = C[i-1][3] + C[i-1][4] + C[i-1][5];
        C[i][5] = C[i-1][6] + C[i-1][7] + C[i-1][8];
        C[i][6] = C[i-1][0] + C[i-1][1] + C[i-1][2];
        C[i][7] = C[i-1][3] + C[i-1][4] + C[i-1][5];
        C[i][8] = C[i-1][6] + C[i-1][7] + C[i-1][8];
    }
}

// C [n, 'AA'] = C[n-1, 'AA'] + C[n-1, 'AB'] + C[n-1,'AC']
// C [n, 'AB'] = C[n-1, 'BA'] + C[n-1, 'BB']
// C [n, 'AC'] = C[n-1, 'CA'] + C[n-1, 'CB'] + C[n-1, 'CC']
// C [n, 'BA'] = C[n-1, 'AA'] + C[n-1, 'AB'] + C[n-1, 'AC']
// C [n, 'BB'] = C[n-1, 'BA'] + C[n-1, 'BB'] + C[n-1, 'BC']
// C [n, 'BC'] = C[n-1, 'CA'] + C[n-1, 'CB'] + C[n-1, 'CC']
// C [n, 'CA'] = C[n-1, 'AA'] + C[n-1, 'AB'] + C[n-1, 'AC']
// C [n, 'CB'] = C[n-1, 'BA'] + C[n-1, 'BB'] + C[n-1, 'BC']
// C [n, 'CC'] = C[n-1, 'CA'] + C[n-1, 'CB'] + C[n-1, 'CC']



int
main () {
    for (unsigned int i = 3; i < 10; ++i) {
        calc (i);

        unsigned int s = 0;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
            s += C[i][j];
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `i >= 2`:

Let `same[i]` be the number of allowed (i.e. not forbidden) strings of length `i` that end in two identical characters.
Let `diff[i]` be the number of allowed strings of length `i` that end in two different characters.

Then `same[2] = 3`, `diff[2] = 6`, and for `i >= 2`,

```
same[i+1] = same[i] + diff[i]  
diff[i+1] = 2 * same[i] + diff[i]
```

What we want is `n[i] = s[i] + d[i]`; the above equations give us

```
n[2] = 9
n[i+1] = 2 * n[i] + n[i-1]
```

With this you can calculate `n[i]` in essentially linear time.